# Adding Multiple Storage Plugins in Apache Drill for S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-drill

I want to take a join on tables in two different S3 sources using Apache Drill. Is there a way to add AWS access keys and secret keys in conf/core-site.xml file? Or is there any other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storage plugin configuration that you have for S3, the connection
URL can be written like “s3n://accessKeyId:secretKeyId@bucket”. This way you can have as many S3 sources configured with your Drillbit cluster as you want.